# Intersection of two ranges

Tags: google-sheets

Example:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WsFnYIy0ATiGAn5ylL4kIQY3tQ-oBxN1qTwclhR8SBo

I can easily merge two ranges. Example in D2.
But I'd like to get intersections of range.

In F column I have manually written what I'd like to get. It is an intersection of two ranges. That is California+Texas-Exception.

In other words I'd like to get intersection of two ranges.

Could you give me a hint here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=filter(D2:D; len(D2:D); isna(match(D2:D; E2:E; 0)))
```

and see if that works for you?